# C# .NET Core 3.1 code works well as long executed with Visual Studio, but published single file executable is consuming tremendous amount of memory

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I wanted to release my application because it was working well. But when I was running it as a packaged application, it was using an tremendous amount of memory up to 20 GByte and more. Running it in Visual Studio 2019, I can't reproduce the problem. It is also running very long, where in VS even with many files it's a few seconds.

I tried I think almost everything so far, removed all the parallelism, ConcurrentQueue to Queue etc. But the problem persists.

https://github.com/rmoergeli/ConsoleAppConcurrentMemoryProblem

VS and executable, you have to "Run as administrator".

Comment: 20GB of RAM is almost certainly a memory leak, probably caused by creating and garbage-collecting a ton of temporary objects, or forgetting to dispose objects that do need disposing. Perhaps the objects are still referenced by the app, so they can't be GC'd?  This has nothing to do with parallelism or ConcurrentQueue etc

Comment: I just looked at the code.It needs severe simplification as it uses the obsolete BackgroundWorker *and* a Task as if it were a thread instead of a task, *and* PLINQ *and* Concurrent queues. For starters, BGW is completely replaced by `Task.Run`. If you want to report progress, use the `Progress<T>` class. Task aren't threads either, they represent jobs (tasks) that will run on a thread and so, *shouldn't* run forever. Finally, `PLINQ` and `Parallel` are meant to process lots of data in parallel, ie using *all* available cores. They aren't meant to process stuff concurrently

Comment: If you want to process lots of files perhaps *all* you need is to use an `ActionBlock<T>` with a degree of parallelism setting>1 and post files to it in a loop. An ActionBlock already has an input queue, so you don't need ConcurrentQueue or semaphores

Comment: Even that could quickly fill your memory with cached objects. Perhaps *that's* what happens here - VS runs too slowly for you to notice, but in a release build, all local files end up cached in memory because the worker methods are too slow to process them due to semaphores, tasks and PLINQ blocking each other. To fix this, set the block's `BoundedCapacity` to a fixed number instead of infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to process all files on a drive in parallel, and probably end up caching every file in memory, because the worker methods end up blocking each other. Running under a debugger is too slow for this to happen.

.NET already provides mechanisms for processing individual messages in a pipeline of steps with multiple threads, *and* constraining how many items can be in memory at a time.

It's quite likely all you need is to use a single [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.1) or [TransformBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2?view=netcore-3.1) class. Those classes accept messages in their input buffers and process them in-order using one or more worker tasks. They also allow setting a boundary to their input buffers to avoid buffer overflows, if the workers are too slow.

To solve your problem, perhaps all you need is an ActionBlock with a DOP>1 and a limited input buffer, eg :

```
var options=new new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
         BoundedCapacity=10
});
var block=new ActionBlock<string>(filePath=>{
  //Do something with that file
},options);

//Feed all files to the block

foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\","*",SearchOptions.AllDirectories))
{
    await block.SendAsync(file);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

This will feed all files to the block, waiting if there are more than 10 items waiting in the input buffer. Each item will be processed on a separate task. At most 5 items will be processed concurrently. In the end, it will await for the block to complete processing all buffered messages before exiting.

The `C:\` folder contains inaccessible folders that would raise an exception if you tried to read them. To avoid this, you can use [EnumerationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `SearchOptions` :

```
var enumOptions=new EnumerationOptions { 
    IgnoreInaccessible=true, 
    RecurseSubdirectories=true
};

foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\","*",options))
{
    await block.SendAsync(file);
}
```

**Problems with the current code**

The code is overcomplicated and uses multiple concurrency and parallelism constructs in inappropriate or even conflicting ways. It looks like it's trying to process all the files in a local disk but ends ups loading every file (or at least every file name or FileInfo object) in memory, waiting for some blocked methods to process them.  Most likely, running this in Visual Studio is too slow to exhibit this behaviour.

- For starters, BackgroundWorker is obsolete, completely replaced since 2012 by Task and the Progress class for progress reporting. That's 8 years. There's no valid reason to use it any more.
- A Task is not a thread, it's just a job (task) that will run on a thread at some point. It's not meant to stay alive for a long time and *definitely* not meant to act as a thread with a loop.
- PLINQ and the methods of the `Parallel` class are meant for parallelism - CPU-heavy processing of lots of in-memory data by using *all* available cores. They aren't meant for concurrency, where different operations need to happen at the same time, especially not IO scenarios that don't need the CPU.
- Adding semaphores only makes things work by getting all those constructs to block each other.